# SOAP-Laravel-CRUD

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando `laravel`, `ubuntu`, `apache2` e a biblioteca `zendframework/zend-soap`. Eu consegui fazer o `client-soap` e estou tentando fazer o `server-soap`. Eu consegui fazer um select com o `server-soap` no BD remoto(mssql) mas não consigo fazer o *insert*. Aqui está o meu projeto:  https://github.com/agnerbzrao/SOAP-Agner, e o método pra fazer o *insert* está em: https://github.com/agnerbzrao/SOAP-Agner/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/SOAP/ClientController.php